# Want to map a network dive to G, but G doesn't appear as an option. How do I do this?

Tags: windows-7, network-drive

I have an HP computer running Windows 7.  I am trying to map my server as network drive "G".
"G" doesn't appear as an option.   I need to have it mapped as "G"so it is consistent with my other work stations because of software I am running.  How do I do this?  I am running my network using MS exchange, 2003

Answer (score 1):

That is because it is already in use. You need to change whatever internal/external hard drive or disk drive that is already using `G:` to another drive letter. You do this within Windows Disk Management utility. It can be reach by hitting start and typing `diskmgmt.msc`. The utility has a split view. The bottom half is the part you want to be working with. Find whatever drive is already using `G:`, right click it then select **Change Drive Letter and Path...**. I believe you can figure out the rest.